# Django TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django

After i uploaded my django project from my local machine to a remote server this error appears

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

registration/login.html

Request Method: GET Request URL: http://ip:8000/ Django Version: 1.8.6 Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:

registration/login.html

Exception Location: /home/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 46 Python Executable: /home/market/bin/python Python Version: 2.7.12 Python Path:

['/home/market/src', '/home/market/lib/python2.7', '/home/market/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/market/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/market/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/market/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/market/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Server time: Sun, 2 Jul 2017 08:35:49 +0000
```

and this error appears in django server console

```
(1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.
```

**TEMPLATE in Settings**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for blackmarket project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ijpwl*f+r5ewyo6-3eorp)&natbb7nh5oh13h&wllhb0o#)gxu'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
)




# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blackmarket.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blackmarket.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)


# login redirect
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/detail'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout/'
```

Comment: What is the path to the template you want to have loaded and what do you have in settings.py that start with `TEMPLATE_`?

Comment: So there is a file `/home/market/src/templates/registration/login.html`? (and please look at the remote server :) )

Comment: no, there is /home/market/src/templates/login.html

Answer (score 0):

You have one of these situations:

- You have deployed the files from `templates/registration` on your local machine to `/home/market/src/templates` instead of `/home/market/src/templates/registration`.
- The same problem exists on your local machine

So you need to figure out which one it is and adjust accordingly by either creating the `registration` directory below `templates/` and move the files there or change the code that calls for `registration/login.html` to use `login.html`.

Comment: in my localhost it works just fine, and i never create a folder called /registration/ !!

Comment: i created a 'registration' folder than i moved html files into it and it works!! i have no idea what pice of code is calling for this folder! thank you @Melvyn

Comment: It may be in the database. Do you use an app for login / registration?

Comment: no app for login and registration, just some html forms and python code in views.py. i will chack the db.

Comment: Well, I know [django-registration-redux](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/auth_urls.py) uses `registration/login.html`, but that's in the code and it must be in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.

Comment: i've added settings.py the the main question. please check it.

Comment: No red flags for me. I would search the code on production for 'login.html' using `grep -rl 'login.html' /home/market/src` and see what comes up. Sites framework isn't even in INSTALLED_APPS which would be the only way to inject a template folder via database.